# How can i make sure pyautogui.locateOnScreen updates frequently?

Tags: python, pyautogui

This is my first post on here, and im also not that experienced with coding (just passed my exam thats it), so my apologies if this is an unusual post :P

I was trying to write a little program that checks if a number in a game (that number being the sum of 5 20 sided dice rolls) is higher than x (for example 95).

I decided to use pyautogui to "read" the game and check if the regions where the two digits of this number are, match any of the images of said digits. I then convert them to an integer and print it out. This works perfectly if i start the program with each roll of the dice, but when i put it in a while loop it always keeps the first number that was on my screen...

what am i doing wrong here?

```
import time
import cv2
import pyautogui as aut

time.sleep(3)
roll = 0
while int(roll) <= 95:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    aut.click(872,807)
    digit1, digit2 = None, None

    for digit in range(10):
        region1 = aut.locateOnScreen('D:\\Documents\\OpenCV\\images\\%s.png' % digit, grayscale=True, confidence=0.8, region=(800, 720, 30, 50))
        region2 = aut.locateOnScreen('D:\\Documents\\OpenCV\\images\\%s.png' % digit, grayscale=True, confidence=0.8, region=(825, 720, 30, 50))

        if region1 is not None:
            digit1 = digit

        if region2 is not None:
            digit2 = digit

    roll = int("%s%s" % (digit1, digit2))
    print(roll)
```

At first i didnt reset both digits back to None inside the loop, so i added that. Also tried messing around with the regions and the confidence, but since the program works fine for every number when i run it manually, that cant really be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the dice that you are using is not part of your program, hence your use of pyautogui. You might not be allowing enough time for your dice to roll before running you loop that checks the digit. Maybe shift that time.sleep(0.5) down a bit to after you reroll the dice
Otherwise you could try checking if your mouse click coordinates are correct.